# How to use the dmafd from iotcl VIDIOC_EXPBUF with sendfile?

Tags: linux, v4l2, sendfile

The ioctl `VIDIOC_EXPBUF` exports the dma memory as a filedescriptor. I want so transfer these memory over the network using `sendfile` (because it is really fast compared to `send()` or `write()`).

But `sendfile()` does not work on these filedescriptor. sendfile() returns with Error -1 and Errno is: Illegal seek.

How to get this working?

```
int buffer_export(int *vfd, int index, int *dmafd)
{
    struct v4l2_exportbuffer expbuf;
    memset(&expbuf, 0, sizeof(expbuf));
    expbuf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    expbuf.index = index;
    if (ioctl(*vfd, VIDIOC_EXPBUF, &expbuf) == -1) {
        perror("VIDIOC_EXPBUF");
        return -1;
    }
    *dmafd = expbuf.fd;
    return 0;
}
```

Here the transfer code.

```
int *vfd;

//Capture Image

int dmafd, err, bytes_send;
int frame_size = 721920;
off_t offset   = 0;

err = buffer_export( vfd, 0, &dmafd);
// returns 0

err = sendfile(socket_fd, dmafd ,&offset, frame_size);
//returns with -1
```

**Update:**

Browsing the sendfile source I came across the error occurs while checking the input fd.

```
retval = -ESPIPE; //=-29
if( !(in.file->f_mode & FMODE_PREAD) )
   goto in_fd; //error
```

`f_mode=5;` which is

```
/* file is open for reading */
#define FMODE_READ      ((__force fmode_t)0x1)
/* file is open for writing */
#define FMODE_WRITE     ((__force fmode_t)0x2)
/* file is seekable */
#define FMODE_LSEEK     ((__force fmode_t)0x4)
/* file can be accessed using pread */
#define FMODE_PREAD     ((__force fmode_t)0x8)
/* file can be accessed using pwrite */
```

fails

Comment: At a glance it would appear your device (graphics adapter?) driver does not implement enough for `sendfile()`.  Are you ready for some driver hacking?  Do you even  have access to the source for it?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I am using the v4l2 capture interface and got all the needed source. I do not know what to start with..